# Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: java, android, json, post

В моём приложении возникает ошибка только на устройствах **Android OS 7.1.***.

Да, знаю, эта ошибка может появится при использовании контекста закрытой активности, но всё это я учёл, проверил и перепроверил, а диалоговые окна не предусмотрены.

Использую библиотеку [Toasty](https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty) в приложении повсеместно.

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@2fe3b10 is not valid; is your activity running?
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:922)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:377)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:105)
   at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:746)
   at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage(Toast.java:622)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Comment: Проверьте Toast (точнее context в них)

Comment: Проверил все toast, что есть в запросе. Обработал все.

Comment: И я не использую стандартные toast, а использую библиотеку Toasty  https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty

Comment: скиньте ваш код, так будем долго гадать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я наконец смог исправить данную проблему. Она может возникать при использовании Toast, а так-же библиотек, основанных на системных Toast в версии **Android 7.1.***

При этом пытался воспроизвести ошибку на эмуляторах, но ничего не получалось.

Перерыв несколько сайтов нашёл библиотеку для исправления этого и сделал обёртку для исправления кастомных библиотек Toast.
После добавления обёртки ошибки перестали выпадать в Play Console, а Toasty прекрасно работают.

implementation 'me.drakeet.support:toastcompat:1.1.0'

```
  public static void MakeToast(Toast tost, Context context) {

    final Toast toasty =tost;
    final ToastCompat toast = ToastCompat.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(toasty.getView());
    toast.show();

}


easer.MakeToast(Toasty.normal(context, "Привет!", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT , context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shopping_cart_24px)),context);
```